why replacement does not work with centerdot
a ** ad ** ad //. a ** ad -> 1 + ad ** a
this replacement works to move all the ad to the left of the a terms.
a\[CenterDot]ad\[CenterDot]ad //.  a\[CenterDot]ad -> 1 + ad\[CenterDot]a
this does not, any idea why not and how to make it work like the noncommutativemultiply case?

What is the final rusult do you want?

The key difference is that MemberQ[Attributes[NonCommutativeMultiply], Flat] == True while Attributes[CenterDot]=={}.
You can remedy this difference by teaching Mathematica about the semantics of CenterDot that you want.
SetAttributes[CenterDot, Flat]
a\[CenterDot]ad\[CenterDot]ad //.  a\[CenterDot]ad -> 1 + ad\[CenterDot]a
(* gives (1 + ad\[CenterDot]a)\[CenterDot]ad *)

